# Object to make GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to build an object that group all methods to make http GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests with fetch API. I would like to accept objects and formData without having to specify the content type in the headers.

First I tried to switch the headers inside class as 'Content-Type': 'application/json' for objects and 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' for formData but in the case of 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' I got the error Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data. To solve it I had to put the headers in 'Accept': '/'.

I am learning so the purpose of this question is to know if I am doing it right, if this object makes sense and if it could be done differently.

The object:

```
export const api = {
    config: {
        headers: {
            Accept: "*/*",
        },
    },
    request: async (url) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, api.config);
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
    get: (url) => {
        api.config.method = "GET";
        return api.request(url);
    },
    post: (url, data) => {
        api.config.method = "POST";
        api.config.body = api.isFormData(data) ? data : JSON.stringify(data);
        return api.request(url);
    },
    put: (url, data) => {
        api.config.method = "PUT";
        api.config.body = api.isFormData(data) ? data : JSON.stringify(data);
        return api.request(url);
    },
    delete: (url, data) => {
        api.config.method = "DELETE";
        api.config.body = api.isFormData(data) ? data : JSON.stringify(data);
        return api.request(url);
    },
    isFormData: (data) => {
        return data instanceof FormData;
    },
};
```

Simplified example of use:

```
import { api } from "url";

const data = new FormData();
data.append("name", "Jon");

const response = await api.post("url", data);

// or

const data = {
    name: "Jon",
};

const response = await api.put("url", data);
```